# How to Display and Protect PDFs on a Website Like Scribd (No Direct Downloads)

Tags: pdf, jspdf, pdf.js

I'm looking to implement a feature on my website similar to what Scribd offers for PDF documents. The goal is to allow users to view and search within PDFs but prevent them from directly downloading the documents, as they contain confidential information & only subscribed members will be able to view that.
**Objective:**

1. View PDF: Enable users to view PDF documents directly on the website.
2. Search within PDF: Allow text search functionality within the PDF viewer.
3. Restrict Downloads: Crucially, prevent users from downloading the PDFs.

Iframes, embeds & google doc are not helpfull in this scenario

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's possible to encode pdf file somehow in the backend server, decode the data before the pdf viewer render. Enen user can download the encoded file, it's not a valid pdf file.